# upload file using xmlhttp in mvc controller request.files.count is zero is coming in ie

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
var formdata = new FormData(); //FormData object
var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileToUploadinproposal');

for (i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {

    formdata.append(fileInput.files[i].name, fileInput.files[i]);
}

//Creating an XMLHttpRequest and sending
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/UploadFile/UploadProposalDocument/' + 105);
xhr.send(formdata);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        var path = xhr.responseText;
        self.ViewDocuments(true);
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
}
return false;

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadProposalDocument(int id)
{

    string uploadedPath = string.Empty;
    bool flag;
    bool pathindb;
    for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[i]; 

        Guid guId = Guid.NewGuid();

        int fileSize = file.ContentLength;
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        fileName = guId + "_" + fileName;

        string mimeType = file.ContentType;
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Upload"), fileName);
        fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        byte[] fileData = null;
        using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream)) { fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength); }

        file.SaveAs(path); //File will be saved in application root
    }
    return Json(uploadedPath);
}
```

It is not going inside for loop. I done in one poc it's working with same code, but my exist project it is not going inside for loop, please give any solution.

Comment: Which version of IE are you using?

Comment: we r using ie10 , in firefox it's working .when i taken sample project it's working in ie also .but in exist project it's not going inside for loop why .in that project will include bootstrap css and knockout js and data table also using

Comment: can any one give solution for this issue